# Angularjs infinite digest error when using custom sorting with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have custom sort filter like this:

```
.filter('sortScanDevs', function () {
  return function (devices, option, reverse) {
    if (option === 'ipAddress') {
      return devices.sort(function(a, b) {
        var first = reverse ? b : a;
        var second = reverse ? a : b;

        return getIpAsNum(first.ipAddress) - getIpAsNum(second.ipAddress);
      });
    } else {
      return devices.sort(function(a, b) {
        var first = reverse ? b : a;
        var second = reverse ? a : b;

        return ('' + first.attr).localeCompare(second.attr);
      })
    }

    function getIpAsNum(ip) {
      return +ip.split('.').join('');
    }

  }
})
```

It does pretty much the same what orderBy does, but if sort option is IP, I parse IP from string into number. But when I'm using the filter, I'm getting

> Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.
>   Aborting!

But when I'm using angular's orderBy function, everything is fine, so that problem is inside my sort function. Pls help me, because I've lost my mind trying to understand what am I doing wrong

Comment: Read [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig).

Comment: No, it doesn't do what orderBy does, at all. orderBy does the right thing: return a sorted **copy** of the original array. Your code sorts the array in place.